# No se puede compilar en xamarin para iOS

Tags: xamarin

me acabo de descargar `XAMARIN STUDIO` para `MACOS`, para poder probar a desarrollar apps para `iOS` usando c#.

Realice la instalación correctamente, y para android por ejemplo funciona a la perfección. El problema viene cuando intento compilar una app de iOS, siempre me sale este error, y por mas que busco no doy con la solución.

Este es el error que siempre me aparece:

```
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/iOS/Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets: Error: Error executing task Codesign: Required property 'SigningKey' not set. (pruebaiosxam)
```

Gracias por vuestra colaboración.

Comment: de casualidad te has logeado en XCode con tu AppleID?

Comment: si claro, en mi Xcode tengo asociada mi appleid, o eso indica en preferencias/cuentas,es ahí verdad donde tiene que aparecer asociada?

Comment: publiqué una respuesta, espero te sea de utilidad. Nos avisas qué tal te fue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ve a `Xcode->Preferences->Accounts`

Agrega una cuenta, luego en la misma vista dale click en:

`View Details->Mac Development->Create`

Comment: Correcto!!! Mil gracias fredy, ahora si compila a la primera, me has salvado de una buena :)

Comment: de nada hermano, estamos para servir :D //Dale con todo el power 2.0!!

Comment: te amo @fredyfx soy tu fan

Comment: gracias mi bro :D vamos aprendiendo y expandiendo horizontes en todo hispanoamérica :D